# Is there a simple way to vertically center divs and have them display inline as well?

Tags: css

My objective is to make a timeline going from left to right with these orbs. Each orb will take up its respective 75 pixels and then the next orb will be to its right, etc. I'm able to vertically center them all, but getting them to display inline after that has had me pulling my hair out. I'm sure there's something simple I'm overlooking.

What my current code results in: 
[image]

End goal:
[image]

My CSS:

```
.timeline{
float: left;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
width: 75px;
height: 75px;
}
#divider{
background-color: #bababa;
height: 4px;
z-index: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

The rest of the snippet:

```
<div class="orb timeline"></div>
<div class="orb timeline"></div>
<div class="orb timeline"></div>
<div class="orb timeline"></div>
<div class="orb timeline"></div>
<div class="orb timeline"></div>
<div class="orb timeline"></div>
<div class="orb timeline"></div>
<div class="orb timeline"></div>
<span id="divider"></span>
```

Comment: Can you visually clarify what you are trying to achieve?  Your description is rather vague.

Comment: I shared the photo of what my code currently outputs here: http://prntscr.com/2ucb7l
Each orb ends up stacked on top of each other rather than next to each other.

Comment: Yes, "currently outputs".  I'm trying to understand what the **final results** should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```css
.parent { white-space: nowrap; }

.timeline{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#divider {
  background-color: #bababa;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: 39.5px; /* = 75px/2 + 4px/2 */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="divider"></div>
  <div class="orb timeline"></div>
  <div class="orb timeline"></div>
  <div class="orb timeline"></div>
  <!-- and so on... -->
</div>
```

**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gopofoxe/1/edit)**

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gopofoxe/2/edit)** *(With borders around the bullets)*

Comment: It allows me to line up the orbs horizontally, but they still stay at the top of the page. The whole thing needs to be vertically centered.

Comment: @montelc0 Here is the **[Updated demo](http://jsbin.com/gopofoxe/6/edit)** to fit your needs.